# ios universal app xib file names

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

When I create a new universal app, I see that initial controller xib files have suffix of "_iPad" and "_iPhone".

This is fine, and I understand that app delegate selects the correct file by userInterfaceIdiom

However, I read that I could achieve the same effect with the suffixes of "~iPad" and "~iPhone" automatically

I am very curious about this. If this selection can be done by adding a tilde (~) notation, why doesnt the default universal app file structure use it?

Comment: I guess there is no reason that would satisfy you. Some people prefer automatisms, some prefer to control everything themselves. Seems that even among Apple's own developers there are both kinds of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. 
Iam using ~ipad and ~iphone for loading images from application bundle and it works like a charm. It saved me a lot of work, because this approach is pretty strait forward. As Till said people are different and some loves to control everything and some not :)